# Finding possible URL parameters

Tags: php, ruby, mechanize

I am attempting to write a web scraper in Ruby/Mechanize. One thing I am trying to implement is a function which can find potential URL Parameters. Here's a snippet:

```
require 'mechanize'
def find_parameters(url)
    mechanize = Mechanize.new
    result = []
    # build list of potential parameters at URL
    result # return
end
```

Imagine sending passing in the URL `http://example.com/`. On `example.com` there is an `index.php` file which takes in a URL parameter call `baz`, and prints the value of that parameter to the page.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['baz'])) {
        echo $_GET['baz'];
    }
?>
```

Thus `http://example.com?baz=123` will go to a page that prints `123`. We know looking through the source code that `baz` is a potential paramter, is there any way to get Mechanize to find all the potential parameters and return a list of them?

Ex: `find_parameters('http://example.com/') => ['baz']`

Comment: Note: Filenames in `require` are almost always lower-case. This may work on a case-insensitive filesystem, but will break on a case-sensitive one.

Comment: ^ noted and fixed

Comment: Nope, impossible. If the page is not documenting its parameters in any way, you can't find out what they are.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the string:

```
require 'mechanize'
def find_parameters(url)
  mechanize = Mechanize.new
  result = []
  mechanize.get(url)  #go to the page
  # get the current page, split in the possible parameters list, split by parameters
  # (rescue in case there are no params)
  ( mechanize.page.uri.to_s.split("?")[1].split("&") rescue []).each do |key_val| 
    # split the pair of param and value, and store the param name
    result << key_val.split("=")[0]
  end
  return result
end
```

Comment: Huh? Here the parameters are _already_ in the url. No need to load the page, just parse the url string.

Comment: it's possible that www.example.com, when loaded returns the www.example.com?baz=123, at least this is how I interpret it.

Comment: The provided php example will not do that. Question is how can one find those "hidden" parameters?